# android exchange data between activity to service

Tags: android, service, xmpp

I am creating an xmpp chat client for android. Everything related to asmack has been done and i can retrieve and show the friends list in the main activity. also i am able to receive chat messages from my friends. i am unable to send data from chat window to the service. so that i can reply and send chat messages to my friends. i have looked into examples but no one has exactly what i want. notice that i cant use onbind method because the service is not bound to any activity in particular but a number of activities can send data to the service.
a logical explanation would be good. if some one knows about some code sample which exactly does this would be great.
also i need to update chat window from the service when the xmpp connection recieves a chat message.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Override onStart Method in your service.OnStart method you can get intent of Activity. If you want to pass ArrayList from activity to service,you can convert your arraylist to array.

In you Activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityName.this,Service.class);         
Bundle b=new Bundle()
b.putStringArray("Array", your_array)
intent.putExtras(b);
startService(intent);
```

in you service

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    String[] Array = b.getStringArray("Array");
}
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for your reply. but the activity is already started on android boot and will keep on running. how ever whenever some chat window activity sends this intent will this onstart method be called every time? also multiple chat windows will be there at a time so i am a little unclear about when the onstart method will be called in activity life cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can define a BroadcastReceiver into Service and can sendBroadcast message by any number of activities, also You can define a Broadcast Receiver into Activity, which might be listen to The message sent by service.